# Why does WepPi commandline not list the same products as the GUI does?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, web-platform-installer

When trying to install PHP via the webPi command line (WebpiCmdLine.exe /Products:PHP53) it says:
*'The following products are not available on this machine or already installed: PHP53'*

When searching and installing via the GUI of Web Platform Installer it works just fine. 
Also the tool does not list PHP where the GUI does.

So why is it working with the GUI but not working with the commandline tool?

Answer (score 0):

WebPICmdLine can only show MORE products than the UI, because some products (often dependencies) are defined in the feeds in such a way that they don't appear in the UI, but WebPICmdLine will list them anyway.

It is possible that the product is already installed. You can check what is installed `WebPICmdLine /List:Installed` and what is available `WebPICmdLine /List:Available`.